# Contact script doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm creating my website and I have problem with my contact form. I've found contact script in PHP and I try to configure it. When I sent form the page is loading for a long time, and then nothing was happening - mail didn't delivery and didn't show any error. Have you any suggest? Below my code

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
            <input class="cntct" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" />
            <input class="cntct" name="name_c" type="text" placeholder="Imię dziecka" />
            <input class="cntct" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Telefon kontaktowy" />
            <input class="cntct" name="mail" type="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail" />
            <textarea name="text" placeholder="Treść wiadomości"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Wyślij!" />
</form>

<?php



require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$name=strval($_POST['name']);
$name_c=strval($_POST['name_c']);
$tresc=strval($_POST['text']);
$telefon=strval($_POST['phone']);
$email=strval($_POST['mail']);

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'serwer1628804.home.pl';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'kontakt@yyy.pl';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('kontakt@yyy.pl', 'Formularz kontaktowy');
// $mail->addAddress('kontakt@yyy..pl', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('kontakt.p@gmail.com');               // Name is optional

// $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
// $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
// $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//
// $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Kontakt '.$name;
$mail->Body    = '<h2>Kontakt: '.$name.'</h2><p>'.$tresc.'</p><ul><li>'.$name_c.'</li><li>'.$telefon.'</li><li>'.$email."</li></ul>";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Wiadomość nie mogła zostać przesłana Emotikon frown.';
    echo 'Błąd: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Wysłano Emotikon smile ';
}

?>
```

Comment: if you didn't get an error from php, then the ONLY thing you can do is check your mail server's logs to see what happened when php handed over the email. php's job is the equivalent of walking down to the street corner and tossing the envelope into the mailbox. after that, it's done.

Comment: The php code you have is included, is the complete code of sendmail.php?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole code of sendmail.php (without html elements like <head>, <body> etc)